# Why does ‘much’ sometimes sound incorrect but not ‘so much’?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

Example

> I love this so much.
>
> I love this much.

There should be more cases, but I cannot think of anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Much* is a pronoun or adjective, but not really an adverb.

*So {adjective}* or *very {adjective}* are adverb phrases, so this gets around the above.  Without the *so* or *very* it doesn't work unless the verb is *to be* or other copular.